# Heroku & Pip: AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: heroku, pip, pipenv

When I try to deploy to Heroku, the following error occurs:

```
remote:          File "/tmp/build_283a27430a6f3f4cbf76d08e0f6a61d6/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
remote:            orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
remote:        AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

[This issue seems to be related to Pip](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/885). From what I understand, it can be solved by running:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

But I can't specify the version of setuptools on Heroku. [From the official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#libraries):

> The following libraries are used by the platform for managing and
>   running Python applications and cannot be specified.
>   Setuptools 23.1.0: Python packaging tools.
>   Pip 9.0.1: Application dependency resolution.
>   If your application declares these dependencies in a requirements.txt or Pipfile, unexpected behavior may occur.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like this issue has been solved yesterday](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/pull/799).

Removing the heroku application and creating a new one (so that it updates Pipenv) should do the trick!